# How to find image of varying size within another image (OpenCV Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to create a program that will identify if an image ('template.png') is within another (template.png).

This is what I have so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

methods = {1: cv2.TM_CCOEFF, 2: cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, 3: cv2.TM_CCORR,
            4: cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, 5: cv2.TM_SQDIFF, 6: cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED}

for n, m in methods.items():
    img_rgb = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
    template = cv2.imread('template.png')
    w, h = template.shape[:-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb, template, m)
    threshold = .9
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imwrite(f'{n}_result.png', img_rgb)
```

This works currently if I take a screenshot of a small portion of "image.jpg" and use that as "template.png", however it does not work when "template.png" is a different size.

The template.png file may appear within the image at a different size than its original. How can I check if the image is contained despite its size?

**EDIT**: Is there a way to use supervised machine learning to repeatedly select the element on the "image.jpg" and have it slowly develop a better understanding of what it is looking for?

Comment: Then template matching is not suited to the task. There is a variety of techniques: histogram of oriented gradients, bag of visual words, and of course these days ML/CNN approaches. None of them is simple to answer here, so your question is way to broad.

Comment: @deets Thanks! I will look into these methods

Comment: @deets. Agreed. This is more of a research topic than a one-off question.